# correct way to use 是非 and its meaning

Tags: word-choice

是非 means "by all means". And in English, when using "by all means", one does not need to complete the sentence as it already has an implied meaning. For example:

```
If you have any problem, by all means (say it)
```

One does not need to say "say it" in the example above. Simply using "by all means" already gives an embedded meaning of "say it". In japanese, does it work the same? For example:

```
問題があれば是非（言ってください）
```

Do I have to say 言ってください or does 是非 already has an embedded meaning of 言ってください and I don't have to include it

Comment: I disagree with your English usage example.  If someone said to me, _"If you have any problem, by all means,"_ and finished their statement that way, I would immediately ask, _"'by all means', what?"_

Comment: @EiríkrÚtlendi At least in the UK, I'm pretty sure this holds true

Comment: Another evidence British = 京都人.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use 是非 as a single-word expression meaning "please do" or "you're more than welcome".

> - 「見てもいいですか？」「ぜひ！」
> - 「お礼状は出すべきですか？」「ぜひ。」

It's a strong invitation or recommendation. I suppose "by all means" may sound forcible sometimes, but 是非 does not have such a nuance.